# Playing a wav sample on Arduino when a button is pressed

Tags: audio, arduino, sample

I've been struggling to make an Arduino to play samples (loaded on an SD card and connected to the Arduino Uno board) whenever a button is pressed but with no success. When I run the code it does not wait for the button to be pressed, it starts playing the sample right away.

It doesn't even recognise that a button has been pressed. This works perfectly however when I just make it play different frequencies through a buzzer. But as soon as I switch to wav samples instead of basic frequencies, it does not want to work.

```
#include <SD.h> //Include the library.
#include <TMRpcm.h> //Include the library.

TMRpcm tmrpcm; //Creating a player object.
const int chipSelect = 4;


void setup()
{

  pinMode(9,INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600); //Initializing serial port. Speed 9600.
  if(!SD.begin(chipSelect)) //If the card is available.
  {
    Serial.println("SD fail"); //Write in the serial port "SD fail".
    return; //Return.
  }
  Serial.println("SD working");

  if(digitalRead(9)==1){  
  tmrpcm.play("transMono1.wav"); //Play music file 
   Serial.println("button 1 pressed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
```

Answer (score 0):

All your code is in the `setup`, so it will be run only once. If you want the state of the button to be checked several time try putting

```
if(digitalRead(9)==1){  
  tmrpcm.play("transMono1.wav"); //Play music file 
  Serial.println("button 1 pressed");
  }
```

in the `loop()`.

Also, from the [TMRPCM reference](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki), samples are played **asynchronously**, so you also need to check that your previous sample is finished before trying to play it again. The library gives you a method to check that:

```
if(digitalRead(9)==1 && !tmrpcm.isPlaying()) //check if button is pressed, and nothing is playing.
  {  
    tmrpcm.play("transMono1.wav"); //Play music file 
    Serial.println("button 1 pressed");
  }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Now it at least plays a little beep and acknowledges the button being pressed but it still doesn't play the full sample. Do you have an idea why that might be?

Comment: @saniv  That is a start! I edited my answer to correct what I think your problem is coming from.